# Multi-level feature importance of random forest with caret in R

Tags: r, random-forest, r-caret

I am using R package caret to carry out random forest. For this package, it separate a factor predictor with more than two levels to more than one variables.  So does the variable importance (got from function varImp).

Is there any way I can combine different different levels into one variable? Or how can I combine on my own? My instinct is to calculate the sum of the importance of different levels, but I am not sure.